# Does running JMAP heap every 2 minutes affects JVM service?

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, jmap

We are running jmap every 2 mins to collect the used heap Memory size information of a JVM application.

JVM had heap size of 80GB.

After reaching 98% the JVM suddenly went to unresponsive state. Garbage Collector should have cleared some memory instead the complete Server went unresponsive. Is it because we are running JMAP - heap every 2 mins?

Do anyone suggest/answer what could have happened here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running jmap has the effect of JVM being "frozen" for (approximately) the duration of jmap execution. If it has the "live" parameter set, it will also trigger GC as the first step. What you describe looks like a non-stop GC that uses all cores of the CPU and does not free enough memory, most likely a memory leak. Your jmap results should probably give you pointers to the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. During the high memory we were not able to run jmap on the server. Until we restart the services, we were not able to handle this situation.